# Google App Engine Database code - running independently of the website

Tags: database, google-app-engine

How do you arbitrarily execute Python code at an interval without someone sending a GET request to the server?

What's a proper way to gather and maintain data about your users ?

I've programmed a website that lets you create music blogs. I'm not gathering too much data from the users right now. Each blog doesn't have a last updated field for instance. But I'd like to start generating some of these things now that the site is live.

All I have to do for instance is for each blog, look at all the songs, sort by `date added` and then that would be the last modified. But I'm sure this is a slightly costly operation, so maybe I only want to do it once a day.

How should I approach that?

Built an handler that covers all that stuff and then write a Python bot that connects for example to `www.mywebsite.com/admin/updateDbInfo`? It seems not elegant.

Is there something I'm missing from Google App Engine that allows you to arbitrarily execute code at an interval?

Is this how people gather data? T

The smart way would have been to build all these into the models as I was designing the site. I get that but it was a bit of a learning experience and I didn't.

Comment: at least for python you can use remote_api for those adhoc things you might need to do with the data. https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api  I use it all the time for "schema migrations" and poking around the data when you are troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track! Read about [cron jobs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) and [backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/). Start by writing a handler that retrieves and analyzes whatever data you want to look at, and map it to a URL just like any other. Then you can schedule it to run as a [cron job](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) by adding it to a `cron.yaml` file in your root directory. Make sure you [secure the URL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Securing_URLs_for_Cron), so unauthorized users can't call the handler.

If your job needs to run for a long time, you should use a [backend](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/), which can run in the background without a request deadline. You can set up a cron job to start and stop a backend process.

Here's the `cron.yaml` from one of my [own projects](https://github.com/ecmendenhall/Kicksaver/blob/master/cron.yaml), and the [two](https://github.com/ecmendenhall/Kicksaver/blob/master/kickparser.py) [scripts](https://github.com/ecmendenhall/Kicksaver/blob/master/twitterscript.py) it calls as an example.

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine lets you set up scheduled tasks, to run at a frequency of your choosing: documentation for [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron), and for [Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron).